# How do I use webview to embed the web app in a native Android App?

Tags: android, web-applications, webview

I have a fully-working web app that is accessible using Android's browser.
The annoying part is the url bar uses a lot of the screen. Is there a way to make this web app a native Android app? I've read that webview can be used to embed a web site within the Android App.

Unfortunately, I only know web programming languages and have no Java experience. Will I still be able to do this on my own?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly will need some learning in java, you can start with reading the following :
[Webview documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)
[A very detailled tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=369) (quite hard if you haven't any java basics)
[A basic tutorial on webview usage.](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/08/05/override-url-loading-in-webview-android-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com). It comes with a standalone app with a WebView embedded in it and with native android functionality support. You just need to provide your html/javascript app to it and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a web app called  [MIT App Inventor](http://appinventor.mit.edu/)
and get it done in less than 10 minutes, it's very easy, intuitive and requires no programming skills at all.

all you need to do is create a new project,
drag and drop a WebViewer component, on the right set the home url,
and your done! just connect to an android phone via USB to install the app
and you can even download the .apk to your computer, sign it and publish it on Google Play